# How to find and get values from a json file which are in the same level?

Tags: groovy, jsonparser

I have a JSON file which looks like below. I am getting the parameters for name and product_version. Using both of them I need to get the relese_version and latest boolean value.

eg:- If var1 = section1 var2 = 2.6.0 then the release_version should be taken as 2.6.0.9 and latest as false in groovy.

```
file.json

{
"platforms": [
    {
      "name": "section1",
      "versions": [
        {
          "product_version": "2.6.0",
          "release_version": "2.6.0.9",
          "latest": false
        },
        {
          "product_version": "3.0.0",
          "release_version": "3.0.0.3",
          "latest": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "section2",
      "versions": [
        {
          "product_version": "2.6.0",
          "release_version": "2.6.0.9",
          "latest": false
        },
        {
          "product_version": "3.0.0",
          "release_version": "3.0.0.3",
          "latest": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code snippet I tried out.

```
filename = "file.json"
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
parsed_json = jsonSlurper.parse(new File(filename))

release_tag = json.parsed_json.find {platforms.name == "section1".version[].product_version == "2.6.0".release_version}

println release_tag
```

But this didn't work. Please help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to find the platform by name (which could fail); next
find in the versions the product version.  E.g.

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse("data.json" as File)

def name='section1'
def productVersion = '2.6.0'

// XXX
def result = data.platforms.find{ it.name == name }?.versions?.find{ it.product_version == productVersion }

assert result.release_version == '2.6.0.9'
assert result.latest == false
```

Note the use of the "elvis operator" after the first find to
short-circuit.

If you have to do many such lookups on the same data file, it might make
sense to shape the data into a better form for the lookup you are doing
(e.g. turn that into maps of maps for your two lookup keys)

Comment: Think you can get rid of the first find with `data.platforms."$name"?.versions?.find{ it.product_version == productVersion }`

Comment: @tim_yates Platforms is a list. That code would create an implicit spread looking for an attribute `section1`

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I did this adjustments `result = data.platforms.find{ it.name == name }?.versions?.find{ it.product_version == productVersion }
print(result.latest)`  I am getting '%' when i use print() but when println() is used i am getting the expected output

Comment: I see no obvious change in your adjustments.  That print behaviour makes
no sense to me.  Are you in an environment, that messes with things
(e.g. Jenkins)?  Is your example data not representative of your real
data?

Comment: Actually this JSON file is a configuration file. According to the `section` and the `version` I need  to set two variables which are `release_version` and the `latest`.

Comment: Which above code does - result holds the node from the json containing the informations - as the asserts show. If your actual problem is something else feel free to adjust your question.